# gVim windows; how to get h and l to move over newlines

Tags: vim

I've searched for this but I can't find it anywhere. When I am in command mode moving through text if I get to the end of a line and press `l` the cursor doesn't move to the beginning of the next line and the editor beeps. Same thing if I am at the beginning of a line and press `h` I would like it to move to the end of the preceding line.

Is there some simple command in _vimrc I can use to enable this type of movement behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

put the following in your  _vimrc:

```
set whichwrap=<,>,[,],h,l
```

Comment: That does it. I'm actually hugely frustrated I couldn't even Google that answer out myself. I've spent a good 30 minutes of research for such a silly basic thing. It is shit like this, vim.